# Python Type error: Int not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, pygame

I'm working with pygame, trying to create a snake game. I cannot get my code to realize when the snake has "eaten" (is on top of) the food.

I've set up my snake in a class, as well as the food.

```
class Snake():
    def draw():
        for k in Snake.positionList:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, BLACK, [k[0], k[1], block_size,  block_size])
    positionList = []
    length = 1
    direction = 0

class Food():
    position = [round(random.randrange(0, display_width - block_size), -1), round(random.randrange(0, display_height - block_size), -1)]
    def draw():
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, GREEN, [Food.position[0], Food.position[1], block_size, block_size])
```

The first "square" of my snake is defined as follows. It results in a float.

```
Snake.positionList.append([display_width / 2, display_height / 2])
```

My function to detect whether or not the snake is overtop the food is the line of code that causes the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

```
def isEating(Snake, Food):
    if Snake.positionList[0][0] == Food.position[0][0] and Snake.positionList[0][1] == Food.position[0][1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My confusion is as follows: neither `Snake.positionList` or `Food.position` store the numbers as integers (presumably float??). Additionally, a similar snippet of code in IDLE gives me no errors.

```
someList = [[2.5,5.7],[5.8,5.1],[1.0,2.5]]
print(someList[0][0] == someList[2][1])
#prints True
```

So to sum up... what does my error mean (especially the term 'subscriptable') and why does it occur when none of the elements are integers?

Comment: `Int not subscriptable` = something tried to slice an int or index into an int. Look around, try seeing if you have any ints with `[]` next to them.

Comment: The IDLE example is a list of lists. Is positionList a list of lists or a list of int?. If the latter, that would be the issue.

Comment: look at the error. read the description of the error. search on the line indicated by the error what element could match the error. test and print all of them independently. voila.

Comment: So to sum up... `what does my error mean`: search in the search box: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+subscriptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Subscriptable` means what is says on the box: you can apply a subscript like `[0]` to it. Note that this is different than an IndexError, where your index would be out of range (for example, in the case of `[1,2,3][4]`).

You should print the `Snake.positionList` and `Food.position`; you'll find that they won't be a list of lists (or at least one element of the outer list will be an Int, not a list).

(hint: `Food.position` is 1 dimensional)

**Notes**

You seem to be misusing classes somewhat as a way of namespacing, by using the class directly and not an instance. This may lead to confusion later on.

Your definition of the classes is also off: in Python 2, it would be

```
class Snake(object):
```

inheriting from `object`. In Python 3, it would be

```
class Snake:
```

without parentheses, since the inheritance from `object` is implicit (but the Python 2 syntax is valid and sensible if you need to be Python 2 compatible).

Comment: Right, I see my error now. Thank you for the fix as well as your additional notes.